# Port forwarding between two AWS EC2 instaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, portforwarding

I have set up two machines with AWS EC2 and I have no issue sshing between them. However when I ssh with port forwarding using the command below

ssh -i /home/ec2-user/.ssh/keyname.pem -T -N -f 10.0.0.10 -L 1718:localhost:1718 -L 1719:localhost:1719 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no

I get this error;

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1h-fips 5 Jun 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 50: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.0.10 [10.0.0.10] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/anwk-us-west-oregon.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/anwk-us-west-oregon.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 95:c3:7c:43:cd:c4:67:32:ef:fd:17:00:6c:59:1d:e5
debug1: Host '10.0.0.10' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/anwk-us-west-oregon.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 10.0.0.10 ([10.0.0.10]:22).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:1718 forwarded to remote address localhost:1718                                  
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 1718.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 1718.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:1719 forwarded to remote address localhost:1719
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 1719.
debug1: channel 2: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 1719.
debug1: channel 3: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: forking to background
debug1: Entering interactive session.
[ec2-user@ip-xx-x-x-xxx ~]$ debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
```

It hangs on this line until crtl c is pressed. As you can see one of its last operation disables the port forwarding. I have checked the sshd_config scripts and there appears to be no flags set to disable them as seen below;

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.89 2013/02/06 00:20:42 dtucker Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

# If you want to change the port on a SELinux system, you have to tell
# SELinux about this change.
# semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp #PORTNUMBER
#
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

# The default requires explicit activation of protocol 1
#Protocol 2

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
#ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
# Only allow root to run commands over ssh, no shell
PermitRootLogin forced-commands-only
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
# EC2 uses keys for remote access
PasswordAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing, 
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will 
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
# WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in Fedora and may cause several
# problems.
#UsePAM no
# Leaving enabled as described so that account and session checks are run
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PrintMotd yes
# Explicitly enable
PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox      # Default for new installations.
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#ShowPatchLevel no
#UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Uncomment this if you want to use .local domain
#Host *.local
#   CheckHostIP no

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

Do you have any idea why this is and a possible solution?

Regards

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, just ran into that today.  BTW, the ssh remote command appears HUNG because it is waiting for additional input.  You can ALSO press Ctrl-D to terminate that kind of 'misconfigured' shell session.

Two ways to fix this:

1. Add '-n' to the ssh command
2. Stop using 'forceCommand' option incorrectly in sshd_config